# Converting a Character Array to a String without Empty Spaces

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm having an issue with converting an array of characters to a string in Java. I only want to copy characters that are not empty. Take this code for example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class CharArrayToStringTest
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // works just fine - string has 5 characters and its length is 5
        char[] word = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
        String sWord = new String(word);
        System.out.println("Length of '" + sWord + "' is " + sWord.length());

        // string appears empty in console, yet its length is 5?
        char[] anotherWord = new char[5];
        String sAnotherWord = new String(anotherWord);
        System.out.println("Length of '" + sAnotherWord + "' is " + sAnotherWord.length());
        // isEmpty() even says the blank string is not empty
        System.out.println("'" + sAnotherWord + "'" + " is empty: " + sAnotherWord.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Length of 'hello' is 5
Length of '' is 5
'' is empty: false
```

How do I create a string from an array of characters where any blank characters at the end of the string are left out?

Comment: String sAnotherWord = (new String(anotherWord)).trim();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `trimming` the trailing spaces in the `String` using [String.trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()). Just do : -

```
char[] anotherWord = new char[5];
String sAnotherWord = new String(anotherWord);
sAnotherWord = sAnotherWord.trim();
```

Now, the **spaces** would be removed.

**Edit 1**: As mention by [spencer.sm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3498950/spencer-sm) in his answer, your *second print* statement is faulty, as it prints `sWord.length()` instead of `sAnotherWord.length()`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have an empty `char` in Java. All chars must be exactly one character. If you want to remove *whitespace* at the end of a string, use the String `trim()` method.

---

Also, your second print statement should end with `sAnotherWord.length()` instead of `sWord.length()`. See below:

```
System.out.println("Length of '" + sAnotherWord + "' is " + sAnotherWord.length());
```

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the typo.